# AppClip how to get query items from the URL

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, apple-appclips

When the AppClips open, I want to read the value of the token from the link => https://example.com/token=12ds234vssd

This is SwiftUI example:

```
var body: some Scene
{
    WindowGroup
    {
        ContentView().onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, perform: handleUserActivity)
    }
}

func handleUserActivity(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity)
{
    guard let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
          let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
          let queryItems = components.queryItems else
    {
        return
    }
    // Configure App Clip with query items
    print(String(queryItems))         
}
```

How do I write using a UIKit?

Can I write the same syntax on the UIKit?

Comment: Does your UIKit app have a SceneDelegate or just an AppDelegate?

Comment: Yes, I have AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift

Comment: You should be able to use `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity)` in your SceneDelegate to get the NSUserActivity and then get the query parameters in the same way that you are doing above.

Comment: Is it possible to access the query params from another Controller? For example ViewController?

Comment: You could pass the parameters once you have received them however you like. It really depends on your app setup.

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/responding_to_invocations#3599725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scene Delegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    for activity in connectionOptions.userActivities where activity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let appClipCodeURL = activity.webpageURL
        print("appClipCodeURL: \(appClipCodeURL)")
    }  
}
```